# How to convert a .txt file into .pkl file in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle

I have a c.txt file, which i want to convert it into a c.pkl file , so that i can read it on jupyter notebook.

```
c.txt_file = [("Test1" , {"Details" : ["English" , "Maths"]}) , ("Test2" , {"Details" : 
["Science" , "EVS"]}) ]
```

The above shows my c.txt file , i want to read it in jupyter notebook, so how to convert it into c.pkl file, so that after loading c.pkl file, i get the same structured output in jupyter notebook. Else, is there any other way that i can read this c.txt file without converting it into .pkl file.

```
Input :
data = pickle.load(open('c.pkl', 'rb'))
data

Output :
[("Test1" , {"Details" : ["English" , "Maths"]}) , ("Test2" , {"Details" : 
["Science" , "EVS"]}) ]
```

Comment: Jupyter is perfectly able to read a text file. If you mean you want to read JSON, use `json.load()`.

Comment: Yes, .txt file can be read through the pandas in jupyter , but then it gives the output in the dataframe format.  But i want the same format of .txt file in jupyter after reading it, as this will give me a list . So how to read a .txt file in such a case.

Comment: What? What is "The above shows my c.txt file", and you show `c.txt_file = ...` *Are you *working with a text file?*

Comment: Yes, that is what a c.txt file contains.

Comment: *Yes, .txt file can be read through the pandas in jupyter , but then it gives the output in the dataframe format.* There's a misunderstanding here. Python inside Jupyter can do everything that any other Python interpreter can do, including reading textfiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem without using the pickle file by using the following snippet.

```
import ast
with open('c.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = ast.literal_eval(fp.read())
```

Comment: It Is giving an error - charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4800: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: The data you show is not a valid unambiguous representation of what an actual text file looks like, and does not contain this character; the problem is unreproducible. Probably edit your question to show an actual text file in an unambiguous format. Perhaps see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: @Andrew, the error you are specifying is an encoding error and depends on the actual file on your system. You can pass `encoding` argument in the `open` function. If this arg is not passed, `UTF-8` is used as default encoding.

Comment: @Dinakar   Actually i formed a new .txt file with encoding utf- 8 , And applied the code-  with open('test.txt', 'r' , encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    dat = ast.literal_eval(fp.read())  ..... But it is giving error that SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal